# how to make flutter app check for data access, not just wifi or mobile connection, i have tried everything

Tags: flutter

im developing a flutter app that i want to make it connect to the internet, i have tried the flutter Connectivity, connectivity_plus, but these packages don't detect data access, the only detect mobile or WiFi connection and acts as if it is online though there is no data access,
i have also tried data_connection_checker and internet_connection _checker, but i think i was not able to implement them well, i want the body of my statefull widget to be determined based on the the internet access, when online body: Body() appear, when offline: NoConnectionPage() should appear, and also to continue check for internet access through the app.

Comment: it dose not work, it is like the connectivity package dose not grantee internet access

Comment: Check this                      `https://medium.com/@anilpandey071999/how-to-check-the-internet-connection-in-the-flutter-app-56b8be1fd057`

Comment: I use [`internet_connection_checker`](https://pub.dev/packages/internet_connection_checker) for solving this.

Comment: can you show how exactly did you implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not wrong , you are expecting [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OEXf.jpg).

I have used [connectivity_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity_plus) plugin to check internet connection.
and for better performance used [flutter_bloc : ^7.3.3](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc) (If you familiar with BLoc state management) within [equatable: ^2.0.3](https://pub.dev/packages/equatable) plugins.

FULL CODE:

Bloc part:

`network_connectivity_bloc.dart` :

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:connectivity_plus/connectivity_plus.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

part 'network_connectivity_event.dart';
part 'network_connectivity_state.dart';

class NetworkConnectivityBloc
    extends Bloc<NetworkConnectivityEvent, NetworkConnectivityState> {
  NetworkConnectivityBloc() : super(InitialNetworkConnectivityState());

  bool networkOfflineOnce = false;
  ConnectivityResult? connectivityResult;
  Connectivity? connectivity;
  StreamSubscription<ConnectivityResult>? _connectivitySubscription;

  @override
  Stream<NetworkConnectivityState> mapEventToState(
    NetworkConnectivityEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if (event is InitNetworkConnectivity) {
      connectivity = Connectivity();
      connectivityResult = await (connectivity!.checkConnectivity());
      add(SetNetworkStatus(connectivityResult: connectivityResult));
    }

    if (event is ListenNetworkConnectivity) {
      if (connectivity == null) {
        add(InitNetworkConnectivity());
      }

      _connectivitySubscription = connectivity!.onConnectivityChanged
          .listen((ConnectivityResult result) {
        add(SetNetworkStatus(connectivityResult: result));
      });
    }

    if (event is SetNetworkStatus) {
      if (event.connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.mobile) {
        if (networkOfflineOnce) {
          networkOfflineOnce = false;
        }

        yield NetworkOnline();
        print("Connected => Cellular Network");
      } else if (event.connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.wifi) {
        if (networkOfflineOnce) {
          networkOfflineOnce = false;
        }

        yield NetworkOnline();
        print("Connected => WiFi");
      } else {
        networkOfflineOnce = true;
        yield NetworkOffline();
        print("Not Connected => Offline , Please Check Internet Connection");
      }
    }
  }

  dispose() {
    _connectivitySubscription!.cancel();
  }
}
```

`network_connectivity_event.dart` class

```
part of 'network_connectivity_bloc.dart';

abstract class NetworkConnectivityEvent extends Equatable {
  const NetworkConnectivityEvent();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}




class InitNetworkConnectivity extends NetworkConnectivityEvent {}

class ListenNetworkConnectivity extends NetworkConnectivityEvent {}

class SetNetworkStatus extends NetworkConnectivityEvent {
  final ConnectivityResult? connectivityResult;
 const  SetNetworkStatus({required this.connectivityResult});
 

  @override
  String toString() =>
      'connectivityResult {connectivityResult: $connectivityResult}';
}
```

`network_connectivity_state.dart` class:

```
part of 'network_connectivity_bloc.dart';

abstract class NetworkConnectivityState extends Equatable {
  const NetworkConnectivityState();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class InitialNetworkConnectivityState extends NetworkConnectivityState {}

class NetworkOnline extends NetworkConnectivityState {}

class NetworkOffline extends NetworkConnectivityState {}
```

UI PART:

`main.dart`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/bloc/network_connectivity_bloc.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

void main() async {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'INTERNET CHECK',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: const InterNetChecker());
  }
}

class InterNetChecker extends StatelessWidget {
  const InterNetChecker({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Internet stateManagement"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: BlocProvider(
        create: (context) => NetworkConnectivityBloc(),
        child: const Center(
          child:  NetworkStatusIndicator(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NetworkStatusIndicator extends StatefulWidget {
  const NetworkStatusIndicator({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _NetworkStatusColorIndicatorState createState() =>
      _NetworkStatusColorIndicatorState();
}

class _NetworkStatusColorIndicatorState extends State<NetworkStatusIndicator> {
  NetworkConnectivityBloc? _networkConnectivityBloc;
  @override
  void initState() {
    _networkConnectivityBloc =
        BlocProvider.of<NetworkConnectivityBloc>(context);
    _networkConnectivityBloc!.add(InitNetworkConnectivity());
    _networkConnectivityBloc!.add(ListenNetworkConnectivity());

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    BlocProvider.of<NetworkConnectivityBloc>(context).dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder(
      bloc: _networkConnectivityBloc,
      builder: (BuildContext context, NetworkConnectivityState state) {
        if (state is NetworkOnline) {
          return showNetworkStatus(Colors.green, "ONLINE");
        }
        if (state is NetworkOffline) {
          return showNetworkStatus(Colors.red, "OFFILINE");
        }
        return showNetworkStatus(Colors.grey, "");
      },
    );
  }
}

Widget showNetworkStatus(MaterialColor color, String status) {
  return 
  Center(
    child: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.fiber_manual_record,
            color: color,
            size: 15,
          ),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
        const SizedBox(width: 10),
        Text(
          status,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, color: color),
        )
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: i got an erro:  Bad state: add(InitNetworkConnectivity) was called without a registered event handler.
Make sure to register a handler via on<InitNetworkConnectivity>((event, emit) {...})

Comment: Yes because you may use latest version of  flutter_bloc . Use flutter_bloc: 7.3.3.

Comment: it works!! , but even if i have no internet access it show that im online, how to fix it?

Comment: No if you are not connected to any network it will show you offline

Comment: yes it dose, but what i mean is even if im connected to a network that dose not have internet access it shows that im online, i want to test for the internet access so as to say that im offline

Comment: Oh Okay, are you trying check internet strength..?

Comment: no, im trying to check if the network has internet access

Answer (score 1):

I use this:

```
  Future<bool> checkIfInternetIsAvailable () async {
    final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('example.com');
    if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
      return true;
    } else{
      return false;
    }
  }
```